# Is Death March more difficult in NG or NG+?

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3

I want the trophy for the Death March difficulty in the game. I finish the game with all sidequest and I´m currently level 35. My question is, is WAY to much harder in NG+ the death march? or should I just begin from 0? I'm pretty sure at first will be a little easier, since I have all my skills and all end game weapons. But, I don't want to suffer in mid game. But, if is almost the same in NG then I just go with NG+.

So, what I want to know is: Is Death March way harder in NG+ with level 35. Or starting in New game at level 0.

Comment: What level are you currently on?

Comment: @greg-449 Level 35

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't consider it to be harder. But that's just me.

You have to take into consideration some things.

**1. You'll have knowledge of how Quests play out**

Basically you already know how quests end or what enemies you face in these quests (unless of course you skipped or missed the quest)

**2. You'll have more experience with the game**

What I mean by this is that you've been playing for a while now and you've gotten used to the controls and to block, dodge, use signs, oils, concoctions and all that juicy stuff.

---

So all in all I don't consider it harder. It's just balanced so that you don't face lvl 1 and 10 enemies from the start.

So considering all of my arguments. You may consider it harder. It depends on how you play the game, if you're good at it.

**If you are lvl 35 and you think that playing is a chore and hard?**

Then YES NG+ might be hard for you.

**But, on the other hand if you like the way you're playing.**

NG+ is just for you